# Concatenating mutiple rows in postgresql into single rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing many rows

I want to all rows of a column to be concatenated to single row

e.g

```
   columns
  -------
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
```

i want to have following result

```
    a,b,c,d,e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
array_to_string(array_agg("column"),',') AS yourColumn
FROM Table1
```

check to see you answer
[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/035f6/1)

Comment: Note that on modern versions (9.0 and later, string_agg() can be used instead).

Answer (score 2):

```
create table test (a text);

insert into test
values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e');

select string_agg(a, ',') from test
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/77f96/4)